# Javascript - Replace a character in between %

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

This could be a easy one.. Not able to get my head around on it..

```
var str = "ADV.ACCOUNT_NAME ILIKE '%a'b%' OR ADV.ACCOUNT_NAME ILIKE '%cd%'"
```

Now I need to replace the single quote in the string part `'%a'b%'` with 2 single quotes. The result I am looking for would be

```
"ADV.ACCOUNT_NAME ILIKE '%a''b%' OR ADV.ACCOUNT_NAME ILIKE '%cd%'"
```

Apologies, I am regex illiterate. Please help

Edit: Need replacement only if single quotes are within `%` chars

I have tried simple .replace() without any complex regex patterns.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `str = str.replace("'%a'b%'", "'%a''b%'")`

Comment: You should always show your attempt to encourage people spend their time to answer your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming there are balanced and unescaped `%` characters in input.

You can use this Javascript regex replace:

```
str = str.replace(/'(?!(?:(?:[^%]*%){2})*[^%]*$)/mg, "''");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sjew2i/2)

This regex will matches single quotes if those are inside `%` characters by using a lookahead to make sure there are even number of `%` characters after the single quote.